Could not get unknown property 'org' for root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project
I recently tried running an old Flutter project and encountered a Gradle compatibility error. To fix it, I upgraded the Java version in my Flutter environment to 17. However, now I am getting a new error related to Gradle.
I also created a new Flutter project and the same compatibility mismatch between Java and Gradle appears. The error persists despite switching to Java 17.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or know how to resolve this ?

PS D:\programming\android\test> flutter run 
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G610F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\programming\android\test\android\build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'org' for root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

this is my flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4317], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\flutter\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (6 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2024.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.3
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin version 242.22855.32

[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.99.20240930

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4317]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.59
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.46

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

this is android level gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}





this is app level gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}





this is gradle.wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip




If you need any more code or configuration details, let me know. I’m happy to provide them.
